# Why does this CMake script find "alloca" and still fail?

Tags: c++, cmake, alloca

I'm using the `alloca` function in one of my projects and decided to use CMake to make sure it's available. So I added this bit to my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
check_symbol_exists(alloca stdlib.h;cstdlib ALLOCA_EXISTS)
if (NOT ALLOCA_EXISTS)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Platform does not support alloca")
endif ()
```

When I run CMake, this is the (relevant part of the) output:

```
-- Looking for alloca
-- Looking for alloca - found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message):
  Platform does not support alloca


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So how come the shown code finds the function but doesn't set the variable? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add quotes when you specify the headers:

```
check_symbol_exists(alloca "stdlib.h;cstdlib" ALLOCA_EXISTS)
```

Otherwise, `ALLOCA_EXISTS` is ignored and a variable `cstdlib` is created with value `TRUE`.